# How do I play a sound automatically when a PDF is loaded?

Tags: javascript, pdf, audio, acrobat

For a research project,we need to play a sound automatically when a PDF is loaded and displayed. Following instructions all over the web, I edited the JavaScript for the PDF in Acrobat 9 to the following:

```
/-------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------Do not edit the XML tags--------------------
//-------------------------------------------------------------

//<Document-Level>
//<ACRO_source>init</ACRO_source>
//<ACRO_script>
/*********** belongs to: Document-Level:init ***********/
var bOpened;

function init()
{

    if(bOpened == "true")
    {
        // document already been opened
    }
    else
    {
        bOpened = "true";
        rm = this.getAnnotsRichMedia(this.pageNum)[0];
        if (!rm.activated)
            rm.activated=true;

        //The following alert works fine for the embedded mp3 and shows "[object AnnotRichMedia]"
        //app.alert(rm);
        rm.callAS("multimedia_volume", 0.75);
        rm.callAS("multimedia_play");
   }
}

// call init
init();
//</ACRO_script>
//</Document-Level>
```

I dragged an audio control on the PDF to make this work. The properties of the control are set to be:

- Enable when: The page containing the content is opened
- Disable when: The page containing the content is closed
- Playback Style: Play content on page

The app.alert above works fine, and alerts about the embedded mp3 object, indicating that it's been embedded okay. I can also play the mp3 file using the controls on the screen, indicating that there's no problem with the codec etc. However, I hear no sound when the document is loaded.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you seen [this page](http://www.adobe.com/designcenter-archive/tutorials/pdfsound/) yet?

Comment: @Shmiddty: Yes I did see that and that's how I got as far as I did. All examples I've seen like these do work (as does my code), when using the contextual menus provided by Acrobat, but not when using custom javascript.